# Installing kafka and zookeeper cluster using kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka

Can anyone share me the yaml file for creating kafka cluster with two kafka broker and zookeeper cluster with 3 servers.I'm new to kubernetes.

Comment: Search for kafka helm charts... Asking for off site resources is off topic for Stackoverflow. See [help]

Answer (score 1):

Take look at https://github.com/Yolean/kubernetes-kafka, Make sure the broker memory limit is 2 GB or above.

Maintaining a reliable kafka cluster in kubernetes is still a challenge, good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to try [Strimzi Kafka Operator](https://github.com/strimzi/strimzi-kafka-operator). Using it you can define a Kafka cluster just like other Kubernetes object - writing a yaml file. Moreover, also users, topics and Kafka Connect cluster are just a k8s objects. Some (by not all!) features of Strimzi Kafka Operator:

- Secure communication between brokers and between brokers and zookeeper with TLS
- Ability to expose the cluster outside k8s cluster
- Deployable as a helm chart (it simplifies things a lot)
- Rolling updates when changing cluster configuration
- Smooth scaling out
- Ready to monitor the cluster using [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io) and [Grafana](https://grafana.com).

It's worth to mention a [great documentation](https://strimzi.io/docs/latest/).

Creating a Kafka cluster is as simple as applying a Kubernetes manifest like this:

```
apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta1
kind: Kafka
metadata:
  name: my-cluster
spec:
  kafka:
    version: 2.2.0
    replicas: 3
    listeners:
      plain: {}
      tls: {}
    config:
      offsets.topic.replication.factor: 3
      transaction.state.log.replication.factor: 3
      transaction.state.log.min.isr: 2
      log.message.format.version: "2.2"
    storage:
      type: jbod
      volumes:
      - id: 0
        type: persistent-claim
        size: 100Gi
        deleteClaim: false
  zookeeper:
    replicas: 3
    storage:
      type: persistent-claim
      size: 100Gi
      deleteClaim: false
  entityOperator:
    topicOperator: {}
    userOperator: {}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you could take a look at the Strimzi project here https://strimzi.io/.
It's based on the Kubernetes operator pattern and provide a simple way to deploy and manage a Kafka cluster on Kubernetes using custom resources.
The Kafka cluster is described through a new "Kafka" resource YAML file for setting all you need.
The operator takes care of that and deploys the Zookeeper ensemble + the Kafka cluster for you.
It also deploys more two operators for handling topics and users (but they are optional).

Answer (score 0):

Another simple configuration of Kafka/Zookeeper on Kubernetes in DigitalOcean with external access:

https://github.com/StanislavKo/k8s_digitalocean_kafka

You can connect to Kafka from outside of AWS/DO/GCE by regular binary protocol. Connection is PLAINTEXT or SASL_PLAINTEXT (username/password).

Kafka cluster is StatefulSet, so you can scale cluster easily.

Comment: Please be careful with linking to your own content on different sites, you don't want to be a [spammer](//stackoverflow.com/help/promotion). You should be including the majority of the content here, and use the link only as a reference.